# Eigenvalues of a linear operator $A$, knowing all the traces of $A^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

If I know the trace of all the $n$-th powers of a linear operator $A$ in an analytic form $f(n)= {\rm Tr} A^n$, is there a way to compute all the eigenvalues of the operator $A$?
In particular, I am interested in the case for which $A$ is an adjoint operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: Use [Newton identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) The traces give you the sums of powers. With the Newton identities you get the values of the elementary symmetric polynomials evaluated at the eigenvalues. With these, and [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), you get the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @plop Can you elaborate a bit? In the infinite dimensional case the eigenvalues are not the zero locus of a polynomial. Maybe I misunderstand your comment

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I had not seen that they wanted infinite-dimensional specifically. In that case, it is kind of similar (Inspired by the proof of Newton's identities using generating functions). I suppose we assume that $A^n$ are trace class. Then we form the analytic function $\sum_n\operatorname{tr}(A^n)z^n$ (or its continuation). This gives us the [Fredholm determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant) of $I+zA$.

Comment: @plop could you please expand on your second comment?

Comment: @Stefano In the link to the article on Fredholm determinant, look at the [section on properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant), the first formula. I don't know if you consider that as a way to compute. We are getting the eigenvalues as zeros of an analytic function.

Comment: Correction! It is not $\sum_n\operatorname{tr}(A^n)z^n$ what we should look at, and not the first formula in that section. But the last formula, and the function $\exp\left(\sum_n(-1)^{n+1}\operatorname{tr}(A^n)z^n/n\right)$.

Comment: @plop A slight simplification: Instead of assuming $A^n$ are trace class, just assume $A$ is trace class; the rest follows automatically.